# When hardening my SSH key, why would I use yubikey-agent instead of the built-in `-sk` key type native to OpenSSH?

Tags: authentication, yubikey, openssh, u2f, fido

OpenSSH 8.2 added [`-sk` key types](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) that allow for FIDO/U2F hardware authenticators (like a YubiKey, etc.)

[`yubikey-agent`](https://github.com/FiloSottile/yubikey-agent) allows for the same functionality, except it (a) requires an additional client on top of OpenSSH, and (b) is scoped to only YubiKeys.

Is there any advantage to using `yubikey-agent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any advantage to using yubikey-agent?

This question is explicitly addressed in the documentation for yubikey-agent. To cite from [Alternatives | Native FIDO2](https://github.com/FiloSottile/yubikey-agent#native-fido2):

> Native FIDO2
> Recent versions of OpenSSH support using FIDO2 tokens directly. Since those are their own key type, they **require server-side support**, which has only recently reached Debian and GitHub.
>
> FIDO2 SSH keys by default don't require a PIN, and require a private key file, acting more like a second factor. yubikey-agent keys **always require PINs** and **can be ported to a different machine simply by plugging in the YubiKey**. (With recent enough tokens such as a YubiKey 5, a similar setup can be achieved by using the verify-required and resident options, after setting a FIDO2 PIN with YubiKey Manager: the private key file will still be required, but it can be regenerated from the YubiKey.)